# Efficient data structure and search algo to store a string against its encrypted value

Tags: c

In my code, I have to print the encrypted names in the log file instead of the actuals. Now, i want to encrypt one particular name only once and store it so that i need not run my encryption algorithm again if i come across the same name again So, what i need to store in a data structure is the actual name and it's corresponding encrypted name.
Please let me know the best data strutures and search algorithm i can use to achieve the same. Please note that my entire code base is in C.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would go with a hash table, hashing the actual name. Then you can search by name and retrieve the encrypted value.

Obviously if the problem is small (few names, few searches) you shouldn't bother and just use an array of structures.

Comment: Well, finding or implementing a hash table in C isn't exactly fun.

Comment: @delnan Takes about 2-3 hours I guess.

Comment: @cnicutar: Thanks!! Actually, the number can grow dynamically as more and more clients add up. Thatswhy looking for an efficient retrieval mechanism. Also, i googled for a while to see how hashing can be used in C, but couldn't get much. Can you please suggest some links? I had gone thru http://uthash.sourceforge.net/ and http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/software/AlgAnim/hash_tables.html. How about using any binary search tree? I would have happliy used STL maps if my code was in C++.

Comment: @user911747 I'm not sure. Last time I needed a hashtable I rolled my own. You could probably go with [GHashTable](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.29/glib-Hash-Tables.html).

Comment: @cnicutar: Thanks!! Is this a built-in hash table? I mean, can i use this as is in my C code?

Comment: @user911747 If you link with glib2.